# Unicode Font writing problem with PDFBox2(No glyph for U+0053)

Tags: java, pdfbox

I trying to write some bengali text into a pdf with PDFBox but facing some problem No glyph for U+0053.I have no idea for glyph.

```
File file = new File("xyz.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.beginText();
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, BengaliPdfGenerationHelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("/textloc/Lohit-Bengali.ttf"),true);
contentStream.setFont(font,12);
contentStream.newLineAtOffset();
contentStream.showText(text);
contentStream.endText();
System.out.println("Content added");
contentStream.close();
document.save(new File("new.pdf"));
```

> 

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+0053 (S) in font Lohit-Bengali
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:366)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:415)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:342)
```

Comment: Use a font that has characters (glyphs) for Bengali.

Comment: Check if your font has "S", or if it is broken, or if you used filtering in your resources (for that, try loading from a file instead of from resources). However... even if you get it to work with "S", you'll have bad surprises with Indian glyphs, there is an ongoing (but currently inactive) effort here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4189